# CSS and Images not displaying after htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I need to set-up my htaccess file so when a user inputs www.example.com/post/54 it renders as www.example.com/post.php?id=54

I setup the rule as such:

```
RewriteRule ^post/(.*)$  post.php?id=$1 [L]
```

When I test it on my localhost, the page only displays it as html and does not capture the images nor the CSS file.  My directory is setup as C:/MyWebsites/example and it appears the file is loading not in the directory but in the C:/MyWebsite folder.  What would be causing this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser tries to determine what the URI base is using the URI of the request. So when the browser requests `http://www.example.com/post/54`, the URI is `/post/54` and the BASE is `/post/`. With this base, **all relative links will have this appended to the front of the link** and this makes it so relative links to things like css have the wrong base.

You need to either change all your links to absolute links, or add a

```
<base href="/">
```

to the header of your `post.php` page.

Answer (score 0):

prepend `/example/` to your css and image paths..

Comment: example is the just the name of the website and not an additional path.  So the images and CSS have worked fine up in till I decided to implement htaccess

Comment: `/` is web root..you need to add the complete path upto your css and image files..for example `<img src="/mywebsite/movies/images/sholay.png">`

Comment: If I call the page as http://localhost/post.php?id=54, all the images and CSS are present.  But if I call the page as http://localhost/post/54 there is no style sheet nor images present, only html.  I was under the impression that HTACCESS just rewrites the URL and I wouldn't need to go back and change the hundreds of photo links up to this point...